# $(...).mask is not a function depending on the position it's called

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

I couldn't find any answer (or I was searching incorrectly) but I'm having this scenario:

First I made a simple button that when clicked will call the function attempt(), but when the code is executed inside the function, it throws and error that function mask doesn't exist. If I call it outside the function, it actually works! What's wrong here? Example:

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/jquery.mask.js')}}"></script> <!--This got the mask function-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.number_only').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true}); //This one actually works!

    function attempt()
    {
       $('.number_only').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true}); //This one throws Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that's odd that "inline" code works, and in a function it doesn't - are you perhaps loading jquery multiple times?

Comment: Checking the whole code I do think its called twice D: It's a laravel project and I believe the template import an app.js which contains jquery and this code also import anothe jquery from web. Might be the problem? Why is that?

Comment: try `console.log($.fn.jquery, jQuery.fn.jquery))` just before each `$....mask` call, and see check the browser developer console for output

Comment: @KevinMiranda can you upload example to codepen and share the link with us?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're loading `/js/jquery.mask.js` before function called.
2. Put your function inside **document.ready** like so:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       function attempt() {
           $('.number_only').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I do! In fact I check the inspector and the file is there, yet everytime I call the mask function inside of a function it doesn't work, even with the code snippet you provided...this is weird :( .

Comment: would be good advice, except, apparently, the inline call works, and the one inside a function doesn't ... you can bet the inline call will happen before the one inside the `attempt` function!!